# If we live on the surface of Earth then why Earth images shows maps around it?

Tags: differential-geometry, earth, planets, coordinate-systems, topology

If you visits google map and go to earth we see the image as attached below.

[image]

My question is if the earth is round like sphere ball and if we live on the surface of this ball (point me if i am wrong), then why this google map shows the map as around this sphere it should be on upper side of sphere right?
As per this article 
http://www.windows2universe.org/kids_space/earth_grav.html
all the things on the earth are on the surface that is on the this ball and due to gravity we are not falling,Then why most maps shows the locations and maps as given in the screen above?
I see that it shows only half of the map, as as we rotate it with mouse it shows next part of map, if it is on the surface of earth then why it is not showing the entire map at once on the screen and why there is need of rotating it with mouse ?

Any help is appreciated ...
I am new to this.

Comment: Does anyone understand the question?

Comment: If I look at a football, why do I not see both sides of it?

Comment: what the... ? potato ? 42 ?

Comment: We are living over the whole surface of Earth, not only on the upper part of the surface (there is no upper or lower parts for the surface anyway, you can turn the map as you wish). We don't fall off because gravity doesn't work downwards in the way you think, it works towards the center of Earth.

Comment: The orthographic projection of Earth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_in_cartography can only display half of the Earth at one time.

Answer (score 1):

The projection you are asking for is called a [mercator projection](http://www.culturaldetective.com/worldmaps.html):

[image: worldmap]

It is the way one maps a city , or even a country, if it is small enough. The problem is that with the world a transformation of a spherical surface onto a plane distorts distances . That's why Alaska and Siberia look much larger than seen on the surface.

As the earth is really spherical, the spherical representation of google maps is accurate on relative distances. There are various maps to take care of the problem of  three dimensions to two, for example"

[image: Goodemap]

> [Goode's homolosine projection](http://www.markmonmonier.com/rhumb_lines_and_map_wars__a_social_history_of_the_mercator_projection_39886.htm) preserves relative area and limits distortion of shape.